# Azure AD Latest Samples, authorisation filters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-active-directory

I am attempting to update my code from now outdated Microsoft Helper classes to the new nuget package for Active Directory AD integration with MVC.  The samples are here https://github.com/AzureADSamples

My application uses authorisation filters so the code is not quite the same, I have updated most of it but am stuck on one translation.

In the samples there is a request to a helper class to get a token.

Call Method

```
string accessToken = AuthUtils.GetAuthToken(Request, HttpContext);
```

Helper Method

```
public static string GetAuthToken(HttpRequestBase request, HttpContextBase httpContext)
```

In a filter,

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
```

What is the correct translation as 'request' doesn't exist in a filter, just on a controller.

I have attempted this but it doesn't work and returns a null token:

```
string accessToken = MVCGraphServiceHelper.GetAuthToken(filterContext.HttpContext.Request, filterContext.HttpContext);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been quite a challenge and in the end I couldn't get the code used in the Windows Example working.  I have therefore moved away from the HTTP Context option in the filter and have used the code from Console App example which connects to the Graph API in a different way and that works nicely.  In addition, it did look like WIF was required as it used the Microsoft.IdentityModel namespace not System.IdentityModel which come in .Net 4.5.  Installing the Nugetpackage 'Active Directory Authentication Library' did the trick.

All working despite taking 3 days longer than expected.

Hope this helps others when they come to upgrade or so this in their dev.